# developing a CLI C# application without installing 16GB of Visual Studio?

Tags: windows-10, c#, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to develop a simple C# to test some interoperability stuff and to that end I'm trying to install Visual Studio Community 2019.

To that end the only two options I have selected are as follows:

- .NET desktop development
- Universal Windows Platform development

The problem is that with just those two things selected the install size is 16GB+.

The Java SDK is a few 100MB. Python is even less than that as is PHP.

I don't need a GUI. I can use Notepad or Visual Studio Code or whatever and compile via the CLI. Is there a way I can develop in C# without installing gigabytes upon gigabytes of stuff?

Comment: Visual Studio is around 2.8gb if you only need desktop and uwp

Answer (score 2):

Download .net framework(Developer pack ~105MB) from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net472) and Install it.
Installed files would include `msbuilld.exe`. You can use this msbuild to build your .net project via CLI.
Below is one example.

```
MsBuild.exe [Path to your solution/project(*.sln or *.csproj)] /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFramework=v4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The dotnet SDK (or dotnet core) should allow you to run and build applications from CLI and is lighter than Visual Studio. You can download it here : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

And you will find a Hello World tutorial here :https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/create

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider just installing the .NET runtime and using VSCode. VSCode requires .NET runtime anyway, so you'd be killing 2 birds with 1 stone.

VSCode is only ~200MB footprint on your disk, and you can set it up with different extensions for different programming languages, so that you get some intellisense and the like.

I've used it to do some basic development in C#. I'd much rather do it in Visual Studio but if I had to, I certainly could get by in VSCode.

[(LINK) - VSCode Requirements](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements)

[(LINK) - VSCode C#-specific Programming 'Tutorial'](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp)

Answer (score 0):

I did that a long while back for some small C# programs I wrote in notepad.

csc.exe  (csc stands for C sharp compiler)

Here using the CSC from the .NET Framework.  I wrote abc.cs in notepad

```
C:\Users\User>where csc
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe

C:\Users\User>type abc.cs
class abc
{
  public static void Main(string[] args) {  System.Console.WriteLine("asdf"); }
}
C:\Users\User>csc /nologo abc.cs

C:\Users\User>abc.exe
asdf

C:\Users\User>
```